# Configure Pyspark AWS credentials within docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm using Docker to develop local AWS glue jobs with pyspark. The song_data.py file contains the AWS glue job. I configured the spark session with my AWS credentials although the errors below suggest otherwise. Within the file, I set up 4 different try statements using glue context methods to create a dynamic frame. Here's the glue job file (song_data.py):

```
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from configparser import ConfigParser
from pyspark import SparkConf

config = ConfigParser()
config.read_file(open('/app/config/aws.cfg'))

conf = (
    SparkConf()
        .set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', config.get('AWS', 'KEY'))
        .set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', config.get('AWS', 'SECRET'))
        .set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
)

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
glueContext = GlueContext(spark)

conf_dict = spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
print(conf_dict)

try:
    print('Attempt 1: spark.read.json')
    url = 's3a://sparkify-dend-analytics/song_data/A/A/A/TRAAAAW128F429D538.json'
    spark.read.json(url).show(1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    print('Attempt 2: create_dynamic_frame.from_options')
    song_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            connection_type='s3',
            connection_options={"paths": [ "s3a://sparkify-dend-analytics/song_data/"]},
            format='json')

    print ('Count: ', song_df.count())
    print('Schema: ')
    song_df.printSchema()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    print('Attempt 3: create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog')
    song_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
            database='sparkify',
            table_name='song_data')

    print ('Count: ', song_df.count())
    print('Schema: ')
    song_df.printSchema()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    print('Attempt 4: create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog')
    song_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(
            database='sparkify',
            table_name='song_data')

    print ('Count: ', song_df.count())
    print('Schema: ')
    song_df.printSchema()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The command I use to run the glue job is: `gluesparksubmit glue_etl_scripts/song_data.py --JOB-NAME test`. Here are the short versions of the error outputs for each try statement:

**Attempt 1: spark.read.json()**

```
WARN FileStreamSink: Error while looking for metadata directory.
An error occurred while calling o87.json.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: doesBucketExist on sparkify-dend-analytics: 
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS Credentials provided by 
DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS 
credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to 
load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and 
AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load 
AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), 
WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: You must specify a value for roleArn and roleSessionName,
 com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@401a5902: profile file cannot be null, 
com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@2b6e2cf9: Failed to connect to service 
endpoint: ]: No AWS Credentials provided by DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain : 
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: 
[EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment 
variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)),
 SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties
 (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: You must specify a 
value for roleArn and roleSessionName, 
com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@401a5902: profile file cannot be null, 
com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@2b6e2cf9: Failed to connect to service 
endpoint: ]
```

**Attempt 2: create_dynamic_frame.from_options()**

```
WARN InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher: Fail to retrieve token 
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
....
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
....
An error occurred while calling o125.getDynamicFrame.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: (same AWSClientIOException as above) 
..... 
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain:
```

**Attempt 3: create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog()**

```
WARN InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher: Fail to retrieve token 
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
.....
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

**Attempt 4: create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog()**

Same as attempt 3

When I printed out the configuration dict for the spark session, the aws access and secret key were valid.
Here's the spark configuration dict printed from running `spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()`:

```
[('spark.app.name', 'song_data.py'), ('spark.driver.host', '73d3647fdf5b'), 
('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', 'xxxxxxx'), ('spark.submit.pyFiles', '/glue/aws-glue-
libs/PyGlue.zip'), ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'), ('spark.driver.extraClassPath', '/glue/aws-
glue-libs/jarsv1/*'), ('spark.app.id', 'local-1593063861647'), ('spark.driver.port', '40655'), 
('spark.executor.extraClassPath', '/glue/aws-glue-libs/jarsv1/*'), ('spark.rdd.compress', 
'True'), ('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', 'xxxxxxx'), ('spark.files', 'file:///glue/aws-glue-
libs/PyGlue.zip'), ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'), ('spark.master', 'local[*]'), 
('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'), ('fs.s3.impl', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem')]
```

Let me know if the Dockerfile is needed or any other code.

Comment: for reading from s3 try passing the key while running the job as `gluesparksubmit glue_etl_scripts/song_data.py --JOB-NAME test --conf 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=xxxxx' --conf 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=xxxx' --conf "fs.s3.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"`

Comment: I used ec2 and iam roles and it worked perfectly and using s3:// instead of s3a://

Comment: I used `gluesparksubmit glue_etl_scripts/song_data.py --JOB-NAME test --conf 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=xxxxx' --conf 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=xxxx' --conf "fs.s3.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"` but got the same errors. I also tried adding `--conf 'fs.s3a.endpoint=s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com' --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.8,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8` but no luck.

Comment: I also tried adding the iam role with s3 access  `--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.assumed.role.arn=arn` but got the same errors.

Comment: And also thanks for the awesome guide (https://towardsdatascience.com/develop-glue-jobs-locally-using-docker-containers-bffc9d95bd1) @Shubham Jain. It saved me a lot of time not having to look through the aws documentation!